# I'm installing hd audio driver using setup file, during the uninstallation process the setup unistallation window froze

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-11

Im using windows 11, the windows says InstallShield Wizard is unistalling, the bar behind it is frozen, I can still use my laptop, the audio doesn't work, I dont know if I should power the pc off, the window is still running, just frozen, the original drivers are still saved on the computer in a zip file,
The driver setup name:
Realtek High Definition Audio Driver Setup (4.60) R 2.82
The window displays:

> InstallShield Wizard is unistalling ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Where did you get the installer from? Did you extract the zip or are you trying to run an exe from inside the zip?

Answer (score 0):

Is this driver compatible with the system or device? You should restart your computer and reinstall the old drivers. It may say something like that their are better drivers available, just click yes and ignore it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).